# Get an absolute file path

Tags: php, filepath, absolute-path

How to get a absolute file path php

I have a folder abc and xyz.

I am including the file a.php of abc in xyz folder using Ajax request by giving relative path which is like:

```
../a.php
```

The file a.php contains some actions which are done using Ajax request.

In xyz folder i want to perform same actions which are perform in abc folder, but when i try to perform those actions it is searching for files in xyz folder instead of abc, so the actions which i want to perform in xyz are not working.

Please help me how to do this.

Updated code:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "../xyz/a.php",
        data: {
            "Id": '<?php echo $_GET['Id'];?>'
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#divId").html(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: more code..moaaaar! (because said you're including .php file using ajax, I find that odd)

Comment: including or requesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ajax request i have changed url like this

```
url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "projectname/foldername/filename.php"
```

Then it worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you do something like this in your config/index/bootstrap:

```
define('ROOT_DIRECTORY', dirname(__FILE__).'/');
```

This way when you need to load files, from other locations, you make all the paths relative to the ROOT_DIRECTORY. for example:

```
require_once(ROOT_DIRECTORY . 'abc/xyz.php');
```

This will make file inclusions a LOT simpler and will allow you to move the entire project directory to another location ( production server for example ) without breaking any 'path' logic.

Seeing your code update, I see you're really talking about the request from the javascript.. in that case just leave the full url to the file: url:'http://server.com/xyx/abc.php'

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For example, you are in **http://your-site.com/folder1/folder2/file.php**.

here are php variables:

```
==============================================================================

    ======I======
    __File__;                           C:\wamp\www\folder1\folder2\file.php
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];               /folder1/folder2/file.php
    //$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is the same as $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    ======II======
    getcwd();                           C:\wamp\www\folder1\folder2\
    dirname();                          OUTPUTS NOTHING - EMPTY NOT ALLOWED
    basename();                         OUTPUTS NOTHING - EMPTY NOT ALLOWED
    __dir__;                            C:\wamp\www\folder1\folder2

    ======III======
    getcwd( XXX );                      OUTPUTS NOTHING - PARAMETER NOT ALLOWED
    getcwd( XXX );                      OUTPUTS NOTHING - PARAMETER NOT ALLOWED
    getcwd( XXX );                      OUTPUTS NOTHING - PARAMETER NOT ALLOWED

    dirname(__FILE__);                  C:\wamp\www\folder1\folder2
    dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);      /folder1/folder2
    dirname(getcwd());                  C:\wamp\www\folder1
    dirname(dirname());                 OUTPUTS NOTHING - EMPTY NOT ALLOWED
    dirname(basename());                OUTPUTS NOTHING - EMPTY NOT ALLOWED

    basename(__FILE__);                 file.php
    basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);     file.php
    basename(getcwd());                 folder2
    basename(dirname());                OUTPUTS NOTHING - EMPTY NOT ALLOWED
    basename(basename());               OUTPUTS NOTHING - EMPTY NOT ALLOWED

    ======IV======
    on dirname
    dirname(dirname(__FILE__));                     C:\wamp\www\folder1
    dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));         /folder1
    dirname(dirname(getcwd()));                     C:\wamp\www
    basename(dirname(__FILE__));                    folder2
    basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));        folder2
    basename(dirname(getcwd()));                    folder1;

    on basename
    dirname(basename(__FILE__));                    .
    dirname(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));        .
    dirname(basename(getcwd()));                    .
    basename(basename(__FILE__));                   file.php
    basename(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));       file.php
    basename(basename(getcwd()));                   folder2
==============================================================================
```

============EXAMPLES===========

Home url

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>
```

ONLY current FILE url (like: mysite.com/myfile.php)

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

Current  url Fully (like: mysite.com/myfile.php?action=blabla

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>
```

To get RealPath to the file (even if it is included) (change /var/public_html to your desired root)

```
<?php
// First step: Get full path
$cur_file=str_replace('\\','/',__FILE__);
// Second step: Remove the root path
$cur_file=preg_replace('/(.*?)\/var\/public_html/','',$cur_file);
?>
```

for wordpress, there exist already pre-defined functions to get plugins or themes url.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want to include a file in `xyz` from `abc`, you need to do `../abc/a.php`, not `../a.php` (unless, of course, the file is on the same level as your both directories).

Secondly, the function to convert relative paths to absolute is called `realpath` and you can find the documentation [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

If your directory structure was something like this:

```php
abc/
xyz/
a.php
```

...then to get the absolute path of `a.php` from a file located in one of your directories, you would do

```php
$absolute = realpath('../a.php');
```